# Hired as developer, now responsibilities are getting changed. What needs to be done to avoid over load of work

Tags: work-time, overworked

After 6 months of unpaid internship I got hired in the same institution ( private college) I worked in R&D department and started to work on their website (which almost didn't existed). after some time I developed their Student Portal, Staff Portal which is performing very well.

I just maintain these portals now, and run daily tasks on website. but the director wants me to teach the students the theory lecture, and he convinced me in a very polite and generous manner that I started teaching anyway because I can't say no I have to save my job.

Now the situation is that i have to give daily 2 consecutive hours of teaching which I have to prepare prior to the class, check the daily homework, weekly tests, monthly tests. lots of clerks work.

I'm fed up with this situation now I'm realising that I'm getting away from my path and my development field. I want to get out of this situation and to convince the director to hire a new teacher instead of me.

Please suggest a solution. by the way I love my development work and due to corona situation companies are not hiring.

Thanks.

From Pakistan

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119290/discussion-on-question-by-yaqoob-hired-as-developer-now-responsibilities-are-ge).

Answer (score 2):

Note that your boss may no longer have any web development work for you to do.

In which case you need to find a new job elsewhere. It doesn't really matter what you tell him if that's the case.

He'll just get an unpaid intern to do the job of maintaining the web sites you've built.

> Now the situation is that i have to give daily 2 consecutive hours of teaching which i have to prepare prior to the class, check the daily homework, weekly tests, monthly tests. lots of clerks work.

If you go that route, consider having the students mark each other's homework and submit weekly test questions/problems themselves for extra credit.

Comment: Hey Stephan Branczyk, thank you for your time and for giving your valuable advice. Really appreciate that. I took your advice and somehow making students checking their own assignments.